# Vim: strange character when repeating insert command

Tags: ubuntu, vim

When I repeat change operations in Vim, spaces and periods are replaced ASCII character 172 (`¬`).

For example:

1. In command mode I move to the word "`year`" and type `cw` and then "`yr.`" to change the word "year" to "yr."
2. I hit Escape, navigate to another part of the file, and attempt to replace another instance of "year" with "yr." by typing `.` (period) to repeat the last command.
3. `yr¬` is inserted instead.

This behavior doesn't happen if I use macros instead of `.` to repeat the command.  For example, if I type `qr` before `cwyr.` and `q` after (to store the operation in register `r` as a macro) and then I use `@r` to repeat the operation, `yr.` is inserted properly.

I've only seen this problem on my Ubuntu machine running Ubuntu 10.04.  It is a problem in both Vim and gVim and modifying or removing my `.vimrc` file has not fixed the problem so far.

Any idea what's going on here or how to fix this?  I upgraded Vim to version 7.3 recently and I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer some suggestions:

1. Move/remove your system vimrc (type `:version` see its location)
2. Move/remove your ~/.viminfo file
3. Move your ~/.vim directory aside temporarily
4. Check your $TERM environmental variable and make sure it is correct
5. What encoding are you using on your system? What encoding does Vim show (`:verbose set encoding?` and `:verbose set fileencoding?` — with the question marks)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Your advice led me to find out that using `set cpoptions+=<` fixed the issue.  I'm not entirely sure why this fixed the issue.

Comment: This sounds like a Vim bug. What version of Vim are you running? (7.3.390 is the latest.)

Comment: Currently using vim 7.3, but I believe I had this problem in vim 7.2 as well.  It could be a configuration issue with my specific machine.

Comment: The output of ":version" should have an "Included patches: [...]" line that will tell you what patch level you are on.  The reason I'm asking is that I keep very up to date (I compile my own Vim) and I cannot reproduce this problem, with or without "<" in 'cpoptions'.